# Algorithm to calculate numbers of 10^x smaller than given one

Tags: algorithms

I am struggling to create a smart algorithm. Currently I have produced one which is super-ugly and not efficient because I am casting `numerics` to `strings` back and forth, not really useful to share it here.

The point of algorithm is to get a number `10^x` which is smaller than a given one.

Examples:

- 600 => 100
- 34.54 => 10
- 7.2 => 1
- 0.123 => 0.1

I am sure I am missing something. Is there any smart way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Num \geq 10^{x} $

$\implies x \leq log_{10}(Num)$

Then $x = \lfloor log_{10}(Num) \rfloor $.

$10^{x}$ would be your number.

Comment: Thank you, this obviously works like a charm! Now I am not ashamed of the code produced (instead I am ashamed of forgetting logarithms), thanks! :)

Comment: We can learn anytime, thanks :) @Pijotrek